# Uncaught exception 'JonnyW\PhantomJs\Exception\InvalidExecutableException' in CentOS 6.7?

Tags: php, javascript, linux, centos, composer

Estoy tratando de usar `php-phantomjs`, lo instale usando composer:

```
($ composer require "jonnyw/php-phantomjs:4.*")
```

La instalacion fue exitosa pero cuando trato de utilizarno, con el ejemplo basico que viene en la pagina de: [jonnnnyw](http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/4.0/3-usage/#setup)

Estoy obteniendo el siguiente error:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'JonnyW\PhantomJs\Exception\InvalidExecutableException' with message 'File does not exist or is not executable: /bin/phantomjs.exe'.

He intentado con muchas soluciones como:

```
$client->getEngine()->setPath('/path/to/phantomjs');
```

`chmod 777` etc sin conseguir solucionarlo.

Lo estoy utilizando en un Servidor Dedicado con `CentOS 6.7`

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme, gracias.

Comment: Me no English. You are in Spanish version of StackOverflow. Translation please :D Thanks!

Comment: Listo, tienes razon lo habia escrito en ingles. Gracias.

Comment: haz un: file /bin/phantomjs.exe para ver que indica.

Answer (score 0):

Que mas amigo, la excepción es clara, dice que no encuentra el archivo o este no es ejecutable, es un .exe, así el des permisos de ejecución con chmod no vas a conseguir que se ejecute porque no es un ejecutable de linux, este ejecutable es de Windows, se puede conseguir que ejecute utilizando WINE pero eso no viene al caso en este momento.

La solución que te doy es que vuelvas a instalar todo, pero utiliza los repositorios para esto, instala *phantomjs* desde los repositorios de CentOS o la versión de linux en su [página oficial](http://phantomjs.org/download.html), y despues si instala php-phantomjs.

---

**EDITADO 1**

Por mi experiencia en linux te diría que es por el ejecutable, pero por mi poca experiencia en esa tecnología en particular te digo que si no te funciona como te dije o crees que eso no eso, echa un vistazo [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32015599/php-phantomjs-with-laravel-file-does-not-exist-or-is-not-executable-bin-phanto), que tenian un problema similar con phantomjs y laravel, no paso a explicarlo por el mismo hecho que no es mi fuerte y no tendría chiste que lo explique.